# top 1 case in select statement on TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, top-n

I am having problem on this query. How can I fix this:

```
select (select case top 1 STATUS 
       when 'Inprocess' then 'Processing' 
       when 'Inworkbin' then 'Waiting In Draft' 
       end 
    from ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX A    
    where A.SESSIONID = B.SESSIONID 
    and STATUS <> 'Completed'
    order by A.CREATE_DATE desc) as LAST_STATUS
```

I am getting this error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
select top 1 case STATUS
```

instead of

```
select case top 1 STATUS
```

Comment: all answers are true but I should select one of them as correct answer :) thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the nested select.

```
select top 1 case STATUS 
             when 'Inprocess' then 'Processing' 
             when 'Inworkbin' then 'Waiting In Draft' 
             end LAST_STATUS
from ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX A    
where A.SESSIONID = B.SESSIONID 
and STATUS <> 'Completed'
order by A.CREATE_DATE desc;
```

Although this can return 0 rows whereas your original form with the TOP 1 written properly will always return one row, even if the value is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
select (select top 1 (case STATUS 
   when 'Inprocess' then 'Processing' 
   when 'Inworkbin' then 'Waiting In Draft' 
   end) 
from ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX A    
where A.SESSIONID = B.SESSIONID 
and STATUS <> 'Completed'
order by A.CREATE_DATE desc) as LAST_STATUS
```

Answer (score 2):

corrrect the case and top keyword

```
select (select top 1 case STATUS 
       when 'Inprocess' then 'Processing' 
       when 'Inworkbin' then 'Waiting In Draft' 
       end 
    from ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX A    
    where A.SESSIONID = B.SESSIONID 
    and STATUS <> 'Completed'
    order by A.CREATE_DATE desc) as LAST_STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 * from (select case STATUS 
       when 'Inprocess' then 'Processing' 
       when 'Inworkbin' then 'Waiting In Draft' 
       end 
    from ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX A    
    where A.SESSIONID = B.SESSIONID 
    and STATUS <> 'Completed'
    order by A.CREATE_DATE desc) as LAST_STATUS
```